# Preview contains one word after deleting all text in the body

Tags: bug, ios-app, markdown-preview

Steps to reproduce:

1. Write enough long sentence in the body of the question (I just copied it from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read)):

   > Too long; didn't read (abbreviated tl;dr and tldr;) is a shorthand notation added by an editor indicating a passage appeared to be too long to invest the time to digest. Long used on the Internet,[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thDNV.jpg) it has birthed this wikilink WP:TL;DR to indicate a cited passage is being protested.
2. Use backspace button to delete whole question body (hold finger on the button, don't remove it until all text will be deleted in the edit block):

   > [image: backspace]
3. When all text will be deleted, the last (actually first) word will retain in the preview section:

   > [image: one word]

---

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)